# Vite 3: defining a global variable in the config adds a newline at the end of the string

Tags: vue.js, vite

Vite 3 gives us the option to [define environment variables](https://vitejs.dev/config/#environment-variables) that will be find/replace the key with the value when the project is built.

The part of the config where the version gets defined looks like this:

```js
define: {
  __RELEASE_VERSION__: JSON.stringify(getReleaseVersion(mode)).trim(),
},
```

And `getReleaseVersion` looks like this:

```
const getReleaseVersion = (mode: string) => {
  if (mode === 'development') {
    return '';
  }

  const commitHash = childProcess
    .execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD')
    .toString();

  return `${pkg.version}-${commitHash}`;
};
```

This code runs on build, server-side. I have verified that the returned strings are correct.

In my project, one of the first things I do (client-side) is `console.log('Release:', __RELEASE_VERSION__);`. What I see in my console is the following:

[image: picture showing the output of the console.log]

As you can see, there is a newline at the end of the string. This is unwanted and causes errors with tracking (it causes a mismatch on release versions).

It's also visible in the minified files:

[image: picture showing the minified file with a newline in the middle]

Is there any way to mitigate this, or should I find another way to access this variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `getReleaseVersion`, you are using the the full output of running the command. *This includes the trailing newline output by Git*.*

To get the string you want, you will need to strip that trailing newline.
For example:

```js
const commitHash = childProcess
  .execSync('git rev-parse --short HEAD')
  .toString()
  .trim(); // This "removes the leading and trailing whitespace and line terminator characters from a string."
```

The reason the `trim` you are already doing does not work is that it is operating on the JSON-encoded string, so the first and last characters are double quotes and all newlines are escaped (e.g., `' foo\n'` -> `'" foo\\n"'`). Thus, it does nothing.

* Almost all CLI programs output a trailing newline so that the terminal prompt is on a new line after the output.

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you. I do not understand, however, why the `trim()` didn't work in the "second stage", where I do `JSON.stringify(getReleaseVersion(mode)).trim()`. What's the difference?

Comment: That is because the newline is encoded in the JSON as `\n`, and therefore is not trimmed. Vite then _statically replaces_ `__RELEASE_VERSION__` with the JSON encoded string of `"0.0.0-4afa091b\n"`.